# python3 ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package, they are in same dir

Tags: python, python-import

I have problem importing one of my python fails into another python file. In my main.py fail I have:

```
from authentication import *
from models import *
```

They are in the same dir, all the files are python files and they are in same directory.

The error I get:

```
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/e_commerce_api/./main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from authentication import *
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/e_commerce_api/./authentication.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import User
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have tried to `from .models import *`, and `from .authentication import *` does not work too.

Comment: You did not provide a [mre] so we can't tell with certainty what the issue is.

Comment: @Brian61354270 ah.. I will need some time to follow it along

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried not to paste my whole code in, should I ?

Comment: There is no package that contains either `models` or `authentication`; they are installed as top-level modules in a directory that's on your Python search path.

Comment: The weird thing is that, it used to work and suddenly these errors started popping out

Comment: @chepner How would you suggest fixing that, I just want to import the whole files(models, authentication) in my main file and use the functions in there...

Comment: If you are going to use relative imports, you need to package the files appropriately. It bears repeating: you don't import *files*, you import *modules*. You need to understand how the import system *uses* files to define modules before you start trying to use code that hasn't already been properly packaged and installed.

Comment: @chepner so in models, authentication.py files i need to pack them and then use the so called "relative import" ?